# Handling of references in C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I currently have a function template, taking a reference, that does something in essence equivalent to:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T& t)
{
   t = T();
}
```

Now, I can call:

```
int a;
f(a);
```

To initialize my variable a.
I can even do:

```
std::vector<int> a(10);
f(a[5]);
```

However, this will fail:

```
std::vector<bool> a(10);
f(a[5]);
```

The reason being `a[5]` returns an object with reference semantic, but not a reference. So I need to be able to write:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T a)
{
  a = T();
}
```

But if I add this new template and try to compile the first example (with int), I obtain the following error:

```
test_multi_tmpl.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test_multi_tmpl.cc:20: error: call of overloaded ‘f(int&)’ is ambiguous
test_multi_tmpl.cc:6: note: candidates are: void f(T&) [with T = int]
test_multi_tmpl.cc:12: note:                 void f(T) [with T = int]
```

Any ideas how to solve this? I wouldn't like to overload `f` just for `std::vector<bool>::reference` as this construct might appears in other places ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think specialising f for `std::vector<bool>::reference` is your only option.

Note that using `std::vector<bool>` is probably a bad idea in the first place (the `std::vector<bool>` specialisation is deprecated for future versions of the c++ language) so you could just use `std::deque<bool>` instead.

Comment: `vector<char>` would technically be closer.

Comment: The specialization `std::vector<bool>` is indeed deprecated, but why stop using a vector of booleans ?

Comment: The specialization is deprecated, but it remains; therefore, whenever you write `vector<bool>`, you _will_ get that specialization (any implementation that doesn't do so is non-conformant), with all its problems.

Comment: I might have more clearly said that using vector<bool> is a bad idea because the specialisation isn't gone *yet*

Comment: @Pavel: I am not sure about it, they are probably just as bad from a standard point of view. AFAIK, or IIRC the standard does not define what the size of a bool variable is, so for some architecture/compiler it could well take 16, 32 or even 64 bits. Depending on the architecture and your constraints you might want to use `vector<int>` for performance reasons if the size is small.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, one is, as you suggest, specialize for `std::vector<bool>::reference`. The other is by using type-traits dispatching.

```
template <class T>
void f (T& t) {
  f_impl(t, is_reference_wrapper_type<T>());
}

template <class T>
void f_impl(T& t, mpi::false_) {
  t = T();
}

template <class T>
void f_impl(T& t, mpi::true_) {
  // do nothing, or voodoo here
}
```

Note the code above is un-tested and there would be more complex means of dispatching based on a trait -- or a set of traits -- in this situation.

This would also mean that you would need to implement `is_reference_wrapper_type` like so:

```
template <class T>
struct is_reference_wrapper_type : mpi::false_ {};

template <>
struct is_reference_wrapper_type<std::vector<bool>::reference> : mpi::true_ {};
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, as with your code, if I call `int a; f(a);`, that will never use a as a reference.

Comment: mmmhh ... actually, that doesn't solve the problem ! That still doesn't allow for this: vector<bool> a(10); f(a[5]);

Comment: Of course you need to handle the case when the parameter is a `vector<bool>::reference` specially. Your interface to f(...) doesn't change but your specific implementation does. Then of course you need to extend this not only for `vector<bool>::refence` in case you're feeling adventurous to support other reference wrapper types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you already know about this...

The specialization std::vector is *not* really a STL container because it does *not* meet the necessary requirements. In particular, it's not possible to created proxied containers that satisfy the [STL concepts](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html) because of the reference semantics (you can't fake a reference). Check [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm) for more information. (Also, as Autopulated mentioned there should be a compiler directive to provide control over std::vector in the future C++ Standard.)

A simple workaround that could solve your problem is by overloading function *f* for this particular type (and others if they appear and are not many). Notice that this is an **overload** and *not* an **specialization**. You might also wanna check this for [why not specialize function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

```
void f(std::vector<bool>::reference t)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I know I could overload. But as I stated, I would like to *not* do that. For one, that would work only for this specific case, and also, this is not really a function, but a method in my case. So I cannot have all the possible methods already in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Using traits or template specialization would make it work.

Comment: I presume he wants it to work for any "reference-like type", not just specifically for `vector<bool>::reference`. And what traits would you use here?